# Problem with URI when loading a csv-file in QGIS with Python

Tags: pyqgis, csv, uri

I am writing a Python Script, which should load a csv-File into QGIS. So I define a URI, create a vector Layer based on this URI and want load the Layer into QGIS.

In Python, the URI looks correct. But it seems that QGIS changes the URI: Instead of "file:///W:/test.csv" it uses "file:../test.csv"

Here is the Code:

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Users/Matt/.conda/envs/qgis_env/Library/bin/")
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read(r"W:\QGIS_PYTHON\python_test.qgz")

csv_uri = r"file:///W:/test.csv?type=csv&delimiter=;&xField=lon&yField=lat&crs=EPSG:4326&encoding=UTF-8"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(csv_uri, "test layer", "delimitedtext")
project.addMapLayer(vlayer)

project.write(r"W:\QGIS_PYTHON\python_test.qgz")
qgs.exitQgis()
```

The Python-Output for csv_uri is:

`file:///W:/test.csv?type=csv&delimiter=;&xField=lon&yField=lat&crs=EPSG:4326&encoding=UTF-8`

But when I open QGIS and check the URI, it says:

`file:../test.csv?type=csv&delimiter=;&xField=lon&yField=lat&crs=EPSG:4326&encoding=UTF-8`

I tried the same with backslashes, but no difference in the result.

EDIT:
The problem occurs, when I use PyCharm or PyDev (Eclipse). When I try to do the same in cmd, the URI is transferred correctly.

Comment: Is your Project > Properties > General > Save path set to *relative* or *absolute*? Provided it is is set to *relative*, does setting it to *absolute* fix your issue?